# Writing a code-formatting tool for Java (ie a plugin for Netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

Not satisfied by the traditional curly-bracket coding styles, I've developed my own. Problem now, however, is lack of support by any IDE or formatting tool (AFAIK). I'd like to write my own Netbeans plugin to fix that. I'll need at least a crude parser of Java syntax. Is there a nice, easy-to-use library to parse Java for this purpose? Or does Netbeans have an API for getting this info?

The unique aspects of my style look something like this:

```
  @Annotated public Map<Type1,Type2>
performImportantTask(String param1, int b) throws Exception {

        int variable = smallFunction (param1);
        int anotherVariable = biggerFunction( variable, "A string" )

        return bigFunction( variable
                          , anotherVariable
                          , anotherBigFunctionCall( variable
                                                  , someMethod ("My long-winded string summarizing the day's events") ) );

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean, the "curly-bracket coding styles"?

Comment: @Stultuske Those listed in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style